# How to read from multiple databases in spring batch reader chunk by chunk

Tags: spring-batch

I'm developing a spring batch job where i need to read from 4 different databases (Different servers).

**Process goes something like this**

1) Read records from db1

2) Filter few with the info in db2

3) Filter few more with the info in db3

4) Filter few more with the info in db4

5) Save the filtered records to db5

## My Approach

For reading from **db1**, i can use ItemReader (and provide chunk value in step) and then use **multiple chained processors** for filtration and then JpaItemWriter.

### Problem with my approach

The issue i think with the above approach is that, Say i get **100,000 records** from db1, i need to query db2, db3, db4 100,000 times because ItemProcessor will be called for each item.

### Possible Solution

1) I think problem would be solved if processor is called for each chunk of records instead of 1 record.

2) Or if i can chain the spring readers, so that one reader passes data (chunk by chunk) to other and there i can simply filter out based on info from other database and finally pass to processor

But i'm not sure or not able to find a way to implement the above solutions i thought of.

Are these solutions good enough?, If so how can i implement these?

Or Is there any other way to implement this?

Edit: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546455/in-spring-batch-how-to-insert-a-piece-of-code-just-after-reading-a-list-of-item) is a possible duplicate, but the solution for that question won't solve the problem in my case.

Because i have more than 2 databases to read from and also if i write my filtration logic in write method of the writer, it looks like a hack because writers are not meant for any data enrichment / filtration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In spring batch, how to insert a piece of code just after reading a list of item by bulk, with given list of item as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546455/in-spring-batch-how-to-insert-a-piece-of-code-just-after-reading-a-list-of-item)

Comment: The pattern you described is known as the [driving query pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders) where one (or more) item processor is used to enrich/filter items with additional data (from another datasource for instance). This pattern can indeed introduce some performance issues as it requires an additional query for each item. `I think problem would be solved if processor is called for each chunk of records instead of 1 record`: This  answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56547053/5019386.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I saw that question and answer. But i totally didn't get you. Are you suggesting that we can write the filtration logic in writer?

Comment: No, I said it should be done in an item processor (`where one (or more) item processor is used to enrich/filter items`). But if you want to get access to the whole chunk of items, you need to do it in a `ItemWriteListener#beforeWrite`, so it is not in the writer, but in a listener *before* the writer.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, but what if you have an arbitrary number of items to read in the processor? e.g. for each customer record in db1, get n records from db2, process them and write to db3.

Comment: @adanilev In this case, the chunk processing model might not be the best choice for you.  Surely you can find a way to use it, but it probably won't be the best way.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine which way would u suggest then?Spring Batch With Tasklet instead of Chunk Processing?

Comment: @SanjayKumar Did u get a solution for this then please share

Comment: @SanjayNaik I ended up moving the processor logic to the writer, where I had access to the full chunk.